# Windows VEH - catch and discard a SINGLE_STEP exception

Tags: windows, winapi, exception

In a 3rd party application I'm modifying by means of DLL injection, there's a chunk of code that pointlessly throws an EXCEPTION_SINGLE_STEP exception. I wish to catch that exception and discard it completely. However, Windows keeps rethrowing it and therefore my exception handler is stuck in an endless loop.

My code currently:

```
LONG WINAPI VEH_Handler(struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS *ExceptionInfo)
{
    printf("Got an exception %X at address %X\n", ExceptionInfo->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode, ExceptionInfo->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionAddress);

    if (ExceptionInfo->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode == EXCEPTION_SINGLE_STEP)
    {
        return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION;
    }

    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
}

//...

//in DllMain
AddVectoredExceptionHandler(1, VEH_Handler);
```

**Is there a way for me to force Windows to forget about the exception and continue execution?**

Comment: In simple concole application your code works as expected: VEH_Handler is called only once at RaiseException(EXCEPTION_SINGLE_STEP). I suspect the problem is not in Windwos, but in the 3rd party code. Maybe AddVectoredExceptionHandler is already patched?

Comment: @Nikerboker That is because you're using RaiseException; if you were to throw it in a different way, and I suppose there's just one - setting the Trap Flag in FLAGS - it would not work. Same goes for EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION - RaiseException would be handled properly, but were you to do it directly, for instance `*(BYTE*)0x123 = 0`, it would loop forever as well.

Comment: you are right about RaiseException. In case of hardware AV I managed to break the infinite loop by EIP increment: `ExceptionInfo->ContextRecord->Eip++;` in the VEH handler.

Comment: @Nikerboker LOL, that actually works, which I find somewhat amusing. If you'd put that in an answer, I'd upvote :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to move EIP to the next instruction:

```
LONG WINAPI VEH_Handler(struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS *ExceptionInfo)
{
  printf("Got an exception %X at address %X\n", ExceptionInfo->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode, ExceptionInfo->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionAddress);
  if (ExceptionInfo->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode == EXCEPTION_SINGLE_STEP)
  {
    ExceptionInfo->ContextRecord->Eip++;
    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION;
  }
  return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
}
```

Comment: Note that this won't always work - EIP here is just a DWORD, so incrementing it could do strange stuff. You'll probably want to check the specific instruction you want to omit and then add its size.